# IfModule: When Do We Need to Specify It?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

Do you need to enclose your rewrite rules with the following?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # Rewrite rules here.
</IfModule>
```

Assuming *mod_rewrite* wasn't turned on, the rules won't be executed anyway, no?

Comment: See also the following related question on the Webmasters stack: [Is Checking For mod_write Really Necessary?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112600/is-checking-for-mod-write-really-necessary) and link to the Apache docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#ifmodule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mod_rewrite wasn't turned on, the rules would generate an error upon starting.

Whenever there's reason NOT to be sure a module is loaded ("generic" .htaccess used on multiple servers for example), the IfModule tags are useful. If you're sure the module is loaded, there's no need for the tags.

Comment: If it's in the main configuration, probable on the console when restarting apache. When done in an .htaccess, with an Error 500 and in the error.log file.

Answer (score 1):

From the Apache docs ifmodule: This directive should only be used if you need your configuration file to work whether or not certain modules are installed. It should not be used to enclose directives that you want to work all the time, because it can suppress useful error messages about missing modules.